# Delete Health Kit Data when deleting the app when only reading Health Kit data

Tags: ios, healthkit

We are making an app that only reads data from Health Kit. Even though we only read, when we push the app to TestFlight, we get an email saying its missing the NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription key. We only provided the NSHealthShareUsageDescription key as we are only reading data. So we are now forced to provide the  NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription key with same text as the NSHealthShareUsageDescription even though it will never be used.

Further, when we delete the app, iOS shows an alert asking the user if they want to delete Health Kit data when they try to delete the app.

Why do we get the alert and why do we need to provide the NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription when we are only reading data from Health Kit?

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing with?

Comment: the version is ios11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW49):

> To protect user privacy, an iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0, **and
>   that reads the user’s health data**, must statically declare the intent
>   to do so. Include the NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription key in your app’s
>   Info.plist file and provide a purpose string for this key.

Even though you're not really writing or changing HealthKit data, you're still accessing it.  And in some regions (such as the USA, and I suspect even more strongly within the EU), health privacy is considered a relatively important & legally required thing. So your app's users have to officially acknowledge and permit your app to read HealthKit data.

As for why you're seeing an alert about data potentially being removed, I suspect there is a tiny bit of data written by the HealthKit API's (e.g. to mark that your app is allowed to read the data, or perhaps some logging of what data is read)

Comment: Thanks. I think this might be because we use anchors in reading the data from Health Kit. But I did also notice when the only code I had, was for authorisation to read data from Health Kit alone, when I deleted the app it asked if the user wanted to delete data from Health Kit. Maybe, the fact that an app is requesting access from HealthKit is also written to HealthKit and that explains the NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription requirement as well?